# Where is the option for PowerShell script in Azure Functions

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

I want to create Azure Function with PowerShell. When I get to the point Azure wants me to choose which type of function I want to create the only available languages are C#, F# and JavaScript. Have I missed something? How can I create an Azure function with PowerShell or do I have to convert the script to any other supported language?

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing Powershell is only available when you toggle the "Experimental Language Support" feature:

[image: Experimental Language Support]

This is shown in the top-right of the Azure Portal when creating a new function:

[image: Option shown in top-right]

Comment: Hehe. I saw that button and thought - don’t want any experimental languages. Should I choose another language? Is PowerShell gone disappear from Azure Functions in the future?

Comment: @AllramEst that's something only the Azure Gods can answer. I would predict that they will be _added_ in the future, rather than removed.

Comment: This option is no longer there in version 2, In function app settings change runtime Version to version 1

Comment: @Dafmeister Thank you for that!!