# Write an Azure function in powershell

Tags: c#, function, azure, powershell

I have the following problem. I want to write a Azure Function but need to code in PowerShell. I found several sites online stating, that I can select "experimental" languages when I create a new function. But I can't activate / deactivate this because it doesn't show me the necessary button. So I did some more research, and learnt that I have to use the v1 environment instead of v2, so I changed it. But still I can't change the language and can only code in C#.

The guide to create a new function even tells me, that I can use PowerShell when I create a custom function (see screenshot) but after clicking on the advised link there is no option for that.

Guide when creating the function
[image: Guide when creating the function]

Options to create a function
[image: Options to create a function]

Anyone who has the same problem or knows the solution to this??

I found this link beforehand: [Where is the option for PowerShell script in Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868650/where-is-the-option-for-powershell-script-in-azure-functions)
But sadly I am missing the upper right button to enable the languages!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is the option for PowerShell script in Azure Functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48868650/where-is-the-option-for-powershell-script-in-azure-functions)

Comment: I found this site before but it is no duplicate! The problem is that I am missing the enable button in the upper right corner!

Comment: Removed the close vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your issue, click `create your own custom function`,then enable `Experimental Language Support`, refer to the screenshot.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I clicked on "create your own custom function" but I don't get the enable button... That is my problem. I don't know whether I made something wrong when creating the function or anything...

Comment: @ChrisB. Could you provide the screenshot of your `Application settings`? Also, did you change other settings of the function app?

Comment: Here are the screenshots:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMxPj.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObBAG.png

Comment: @ChrisB. Try to remove `FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME = dotnet` and restart the app.

Comment: In application settings change runtime Version to version 1, this will give you the option to use Powershell.  Version 2 doesn't seem to give an alternative option to .net or Javascript.